# Need to come up with an Excel 2010 equation

Tags: excel, function, excel-2010, equation

I imported data from a .txt file in a spreadsheet where the date of an actual data is 7/12/2011 but I have it as just 7/12 on .txt. After I changed the formatting in Excel 2010 I got 7/12/2013 instead because obviously Excel wouldn't know what year I have in mind. So, I want to come up with an equation that changes a year, 2013 to 2011. Please help how do I do it. 
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
=DATE(2011, MONTH(A1), DAY(A1))
```

Answer (score 2):

To change 2013 dates to 2011 is the equivalent of subtracting 731 (days) so you can convert a range of dates "in situ" by using "Paste Special" functionality.

Put `731` in a cell and then copy that cell

Select range of dates and right-click. Choose "Paste Special" and then in the dialog box select "Operation" and "Subtract" > OK > ESC

Comment: Works for 2011 and 2013, but it seems there would be a problem if the ending year or beginning year was a leap year (number of days  between dates before Feb. 29 and dates after Feb. 29 would would differ by 1)?